# How to change UIAlertAction font or show UIAlertActionStyle.cancel style ActionButton on second position?

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I don't want to change `UILabel.appearance` as it will apply to all labels.

How I can show `UIAlertController` that will look like below image?

Need to show bold button in the second position.

[image: Need to show Bold Button in the Second Position]

By default, when I am setting `UIAlertActionStyle.cancel` it shows it on the Confirm button in the first position.

It looks like this now:

[image: It looks like this now]

I did some research but I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Swift 4.2/Swift 5**

You need to set preferred action method,

```
//Create alertController
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)

//Create and add the Confirm action
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    //Do Something here...
})
alert.addAction(confirmAction)

//Create and add the Cancel action
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in

    //Do Something here...
})
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

// Set Preferred Action method
alert.preferredAction = confirmAction

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The output will be,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add them to the alertView in the right order!  If you want the order to change just add the confirm button second!

```
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
alert.addAction(confirmAction)
```

Instead of:

```
alert.addAction(confirmAction)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can. Try this

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(
    title: "Home",
    message: "Are you sure for delete Reminder",
    preferredStyle: .alert)
alertView.view.tintColor = .green
let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .cancel) { (_) in
     // Do confirm
}
alertView.addAction(confirmAction)
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (_) in
    // Do cancel
}
alertView.addAction(cancelAction)
self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried that but still showing confirm button in first place.

Comment: sorry, change style to .default in confirmAction and .cancel in cancelAction

Comment: than it will show cancel button as bold but I need confirm button with bold text